# Android GeoLocation doesn't work on device

Tags: android, webview, geolocation

I'm writing a basic mobile wrapper that connects to a site mainly using Javascript. This site has a login form that tries to access the geolocation of the device in question. When run on an emulator, there is no prompt to allow location (which makes sense in my mind since the PC has a physical location and an external IP address etc) and the GeoLocation just goes through no problem, which to me suggests that the code is at least functional as far as permissions and webView settings go. When run on a device which has location services enabled, even if I'm prompted and allow location the site cannot resolve my location.

The webView and settings are shown below, and the Android Manifest below that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView wView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);


    wView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                       final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setMessage( origin + " would like to use your current location" );
            builder.setNegativeButton( "Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {

                    callback.invoke( origin, false, false );
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } );
            builder.setPositiveButton( "Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                    callback.invoke( origin, true, false );
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    String url = BuildConfig.HOST_URL;



    //String postData = "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8")+"&password="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
    //Log.e("TEST","postData " + postData);
    wView.loadUrl(url);


}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.toteireland.app" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Tote Ireland"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >

    <activity
        android:name="com.toteireland.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Is that the right place for the permissions?

Comment: try adding below lines along with Permissions:                                                <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

Comment: Hasn't appeared to fix the issue. Thanks though